# Getting "UNIQUE constraint failed" when using @Upsert in Android Room

Tags: android, android-room, upsert

Getting `net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: UNIQUE constraint failed with : appointment.activity_id`: when trying to do @Upsert with Android Room.

My understanding with @Upsert is that it will update records if a row exists or insert if it doesn't.

Here is the definition of the table:

```
data class AppointmentEntity(

   @PrimaryKey
   @field:ColumnInfo(name = "activity_id")
   val activityId: Long,

   @field:ColumnInfo(name = "selected_owner")
   val selectedOwner: String,

   val activityStartTimestamp: Instant,

   val activityEndTimestamp: Instant,

   val activityRevisionTimestamp: Instant?,

   val appointmentTypeCode: AppointmentTypeCode,

   val contactName: String?,

   val activityDescription: String?,

   val recurringId: Long?,

   val cancelled: Boolean,

   val personalAppointment: Boolean,

   val outlookIndicator: Boolean,

   val allDayEvent: Boolean,

   val deleteDate: Instant?
 )
```

Here is the code in the @Dao:

```
@Upsert
fun insertAppointments(appointment: List<AppointmentEntity>)
```

Why am I getting a unique constraint error.  Wouldn't an existing record just be updated instead of reinserted?

From the android docs:

> If the target entity contains a PrimaryKey that is auto generated, then the POJO class doesn't need an equal primary key field, otherwise primary keys must also be present in the POJO. If the primary key already exists, only the columns represented by the partial entity fields will be updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There appears to be a conflict between Android room 2.5.0 and sqlcipher. As soon as I removed the sqlcipher SupportFactory from my room database the upsert worked as expected.

This appears to be the root cause: https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher/issues/588. SqlCipher isn't extending android.database.SQLException so when Room checks if the exception is a foreign/unique key here: https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2191947/9/room/room-runtime/src/main/java/androidx/room/EntityUpsertionAdapter.kt#209 it just always throws the net.sqlcipher.database.SQLException Unique Key Exception rather than Upserting the existing record.

Comment: Thank you.  I was wondering!

Comment: How did you remove the sqlcipher SupportFactory from your room database?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a version of room < 2.6.0, it could be related with a bug fix they did in this release:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.6.0-beta01
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding with @Upsert is that it will update records if a row exists or insert if it doesn't.

It should do and using your available code, but modified to not utilise type converters, it does. e.g. using:-

```
@Entity(tableName = "appointment")
data class AppointmentEntity(

    @PrimaryKey
    @field:ColumnInfo(name = "activity_id")
    val activityId: Long,
    @field:ColumnInfo(name = "selected_owner")
    val selectedOwner: String,
    val activityStartTimestamp: Long?=System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000, /*<<<< CHANGED FROM Instant */
    val activityEndTimestamp: Long?=System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000,  /*<<<< CHANGED FROM Instant */
    val activityRevisionTimestamp: Long?=System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000,  /*<<<< CHANGED FROM Instant */
    //val appointmentTypeCode: AppointmentTypeCode, /*<<<<< COMMENTED OUT */
    val contactName: String?,
    val activityDescription: String?,
    val recurringId: Long?,
    val cancelled: Boolean,
    val personalAppointment: Boolean,
    val outlookIndicator: Boolean,
    val allDayEvent: Boolean,
    val deleteDate: Long?=null  /*<<<< CHANGED FROM Instant */
)

@Database(entities = [AppointmentEntity::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDao(): AllDao

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}

@Dao
interface AllDao {
    @Upsert
    fun insertAppointments(appointment: List<AppointmentEntity>)
}
```

and :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var appointmentEntity1 = AppointmentEntity(activityId = 1, selectedOwner = "O001", contactName = "C001", recurringId = 0, cancelled = false, activityDescription = "Desc001", personalAppointment = true, outlookIndicator = false, allDayEvent = false)
        var appointmentEntity2 = AppointmentEntity(activityId = 1, selectedOwner = "O001", contactName = "C002", recurringId = 0, cancelled = false, activityDescription = "Desc002", personalAppointment = true, outlookIndicator = false, allDayEvent = false)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDao()

        dao.insertAppointments(listOf(appointmentEntity1,appointmentEntity2,appointmentEntity1,appointmentEntity2))
    }
}
```

Results in a successful run with App Inspection showing :-

[image]

- i.e. it has coped with the 4 UPSERTS and the resultant data is as expected.

The issue is likely elsewhere. Perhaps because you appear to be using sqlcipher or perhaps other database actions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to use SQLcipher, and the type converters.  Also, it doesn't really answer the question, why is it trying to reinsert a record rather than just updating it.  Another thing, did you run the inserts over and over to see if they were reinserted or updated?  But I really appreciate the effort you made to help out.

Comment: @KristyWelsh not saying they are the issues (type converters were not used purely for simplicity/convenience of the test), just that perhaps sqlcipher could be (shouldn't be).